# If else issue; fail to assign category to integer category in R

Tags: r, if-statement

[image: Data]

I want to get Category name in the category column using the logic that I have incorporated in the code below. However, it breaks and produces an error. Rating variable is an integer.

```
if (nps$Rating <= 6) {
    nps$npsCAT <- "Detractor"
} else if (nps$Rating > 6 & nps$Rating < 9) {
    nps$npsCAT <- "Passive"
} else {
    nps$npsCAT <- "Promoter"
}
```

> Warning message:
>   In if (nps$Rating <= 6) { :
>    the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used`

Comment: You need to use the vectorized `?ifelse` to operate on a length > 1 vector

Comment: It is not the source of the problem, but there is an inconsistency between your table ("Category") and your code ("npsCat").

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `cut` for multiple categories

```
 nps$Category <- with(nps, cut(Rating, breaks=c(-Inf,6,8,Inf), 
          labels=c('Detractor', 'Passive', 'Promoter')))

 nps
  Rating  Category
1      1 Detractor
2      3 Detractor
3      4 Detractor
4      7   Passive
5      8   Passive
6      9  Promoter
7      2 Detractor
8     10  Promoter
9     10  Promoter
```

Answer (score 5):

```
nps <- data.frame(Rating=c(1,3,4,7,8,9,2,10,10));
nps$Category <- ifelse(nps$Rating<=6,'Detractor',ifelse(nps$Rating>6 & nps$Rating<9,'Passive','Promoter'));
nps;
##   Rating  Category
## 1      1 Detractor
## 2      3 Detractor
## 3      4 Detractor
## 4      7   Passive
## 5      8   Passive
## 6      9  Promoter
## 7      2 Detractor
## 8     10  Promoter
## 9     10  Promoter
```

---

The reason you're getting that warning message is because the `if` expression requires a one-element vector as its argument, and the expression `nps$Rating <= 6` is a vectorized comparison with a LHS of length 9 and a RHS of length 1, thus the result of the expression will be a logical vector of length 9.

Consider:

```
if (T) 1;
## [1] 1
if (F) 2;
if (c(T,F)) 3;
## [1] 3
## Warning message:
## In if (c(T, F)) 3 :
##   the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
if (c(F,T)) 4;
## Warning message:
## In if (c(F, T)) 4 :
##   the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
ifelse(c(F,T,T,F),5,6);
## [1] 6 5 5 6
```

Answer (score 3):

The logic call only works with one element, but you are passing it a vector.  Instead, its just taking the first element for your if statements, which is probably causing you to get all the same category.

```
nps$Rating[1]
```

To fix, you need a vectorised version, something like:

```
nps$npsCAT <- ifelse(nps$Rating <= 6, 
                     "Detractor", 
                     ifelse(nps$Rating < 9, 
                            "Passive", 
                            "Promoter")
```

Check ?ifelse for details.

Comment: It seems we both typed it at the same time :)

Comment: Sorry, then I am mistaken (+1)

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like:

```
##  Create a numeric vector of ratings.
rating = c(1, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9, 2, 10, 10)

##  Create a character vector of categories. Note that we could have
##  used a for-loop here instead.
category = 
    sapply(rating,
           function(x) {
                  if (x <= 6)
                     "Detractor"
                  else if (x > 6 & x < 9)
                     "Passive"
                  else
                     "Promoter"
           })

##  Combine.
data.frame(rating, category)
```